# dynamic variable in for loop php

Tags: php

i have this code and works fine to get the stats of january:

```
$home = 5;
    $get_jan = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM cars WHERE home = :home AND month = :month');
    $get_jan->bindParam(':home',$home);
    $get_jan->bindParam(':month',$janu);
    $get_jan->execute();
```

i want to make some statistics so i need to do that for 12 months. Instead of writing this code for the 12 months separately how can i use a for loop? i tried something like this with no success:

```
$home = 5;
for($i=1;$i=12;$i++){
$get.$i = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM cars WHERE home = :home AND month = :month');
$get.$i->bindParam(':home',$home);
$get.$i->bindParam(':month',$i);
$get.$i->execute();
}
```

Any idea how can be done?

Comment: Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple

Comment: You have a syntax-error in your `for`-loop. This will make your loop output "12" for all eternity. Use `for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {` instead (added `<=` instead of `=` in the second parameter)

Comment: Also take a look at how you address your variables... `$get.$i` isn't going to give you `$get1` through `$get12`. You should look into perhaps using an array instead (`$get[$i]` maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

That Works finally:

```
$home = 5;
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
$get[$i] = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM cars WHERE home = :home AND month = :month');
$get[$i]->bindParam(':home',$home);
$get[$i]->bindParam(':month',$i);
$get[$i]->execute();
}
```